# How to add unallocated space to /home in Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

This is my table with GParted, but I don't know how to add this space to `/home` without losing the data:

[image: this show my table of gparted]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can't when the unallocated space is not adjacent to `/home` - not without getting rid of all of the partitions in between.  The downside of using partitions for organization is that it's rigid and inflexible because you are imposing an artificial limit on how much space can be used.

Comment: You don't say what space you'd like to add to /home.

Comment: @Nmath You **never** have to get **rid** of partitions. Partitions, if done correctly, don't impose any limits.

Comment: There is always a chance of data loss when messing with partitions.  Always have a good backup ready.  NEVER try to resize partitions from a live OS.  Boot to Live media (CD/DVD/USB), install GParted.  Make sure the ones with the key icon are not mounted.  Move all 4 of those partitions (sda5, sda6, sda7 and sda8) to the left or beginning of the unallocated space (do not resize any yet).  Once the unallocated space has been moved to after sda8 then you can resize your home partition (sda8) to the right. Don't ever move the EFI or the Microsoft Reserved partition.

Comment: @heynnema i want to move to /home unalocate space, i need more space in home directory

Comment: @Terrance i am sorry, but can you explain better, i am novice in linux

Comment: @Terrance can you explain me better , sorry i am novice

Comment: You only have ~7G of unallocated space. That's not worth the effort. You should consider reducing your sda5 data partition, coming up with more space, and then consolidating all of the unallocated space into your /home.

Comment: @heynnema the problem is that i cannot reduce more that space

Comment: You also made your NTFS too small, it really needs 30% free to work well. At 10% free a defrag may take a very long time as no working room. Time to houseclean or get a larger drive, or move data to external drive(s).

Comment: It's a two step process. In Windows, use the `Disk Management` tools to relocate/move sda5 all the way left/forward. Then boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and use `gparted` to manipulate sda6/7/8.

Comment: @Nmath  Using this example... **partitioning wasn't done right**... and then you're correct... you hit limits. Should have never broken the Ubuntu install into / and /home partitions **on such a small disk**, especially if you can't give up space from the NTFS partitions.

Comment: @heynnema - partitions create limits regardless of whether or not that limit is actually reached.  It's not unlike a concrete partition separating lanes of vehicular traffic

Comment: @Nmath Proper partitioning, and proper data management (backups and deletions), and the limits you speak of should never be reached. In this case, based on OP input, they probably should get a larger SSD/HDD... and partition it appropriately.